# Property animation of a moving button android

Tags: java, android, animation

I need a button that will keep moving from left to right and whenever i click on it, it will do something. I came to know that I need to use Property Animation to do so. But I'm quite lost about it. 
here is my main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

how do I edit my .java file to animate it from left to right using property animation?

Comment: Have You seen this session on animation of views http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihzZrS69i_s ? It gives good explanation and examples of usage of property animation.

Comment: i've the slowest internet speed. it'll take me minimum 15/16hrs to download this video. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the following way:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //new GetUrl().execute(20);

        // Test XML Files
        //testXMLFiles();

        final Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);

        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // TODO: DO something!
            }
        });

        final ObjectAnimator horizontalAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(new ButtonAnimatorHelper(speakButton), "marginLeft", 0, 600);

        horizontalAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        horizontalAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        horizontalAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        horizontalAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        horizontalAnimator.start();
    }

    /**
     * Helper class for button animation
     */
    private static class ButtonAnimatorHelper {

        final Button mButton;
        /**
         * Default constructor
         * @param speakButton
         */
        public ButtonAnimatorHelper(final Button button) {
            mButton = button;
        }

        public void setMarginLeft(final int margin) {
            final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mButton.getLayoutParams();

            params.leftMargin = margin;

            mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
}
```

For better understanding of property animation, I would suggest [this session from Google I/O 2013](http://youtube.com/watch?v=ihzZrS69i_s) and of course, [the tutorial here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: Yes, I think so. Property Animations is very flexible.

Comment: i edited your code for ImageButton, my imagebutton id is ballbtn
private static class ButtonAnimatorHelper {

         final ImageButton b;
         public ButtonAnimatorHelper(final ImageButton ball) {
             b = ball;
         }
         
         public void setMarginLeft(final int margin) {
             final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();

             params.leftMargin = margin;

             b.setLayoutParams(params);
         }

 }
is this part okay? it's not working..will you help if i give you my email address? please?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on this Tutorial [Android Animations](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html).

The easiest way to animate a layout is, to do something like this :

```
    your_layout.animate().translationX(your_layout.getWidth()).setDuration(500).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```